# Interpolation with radial basis function in julia

Tags: scipy, julia

I have found few radial basis functions like `BasisExpansionFunction`, `Surrogates.jl`, `ScatteredInterpolation` in Julia.
However, I am unable to replicate the results from python's `scipy.interpolate.rbf()` function.

Python Example

```
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(10)
ys = xs**2 + np.sin(xs) + 1

interp_func = Rbf(xs, ys) # By default RbF uses Multiquadratic function 

newarr = interp_func(np.arange(2.1, 3, 0.1))

print(newarr)
```

What is correct approach to replicate the above example in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The first tutorial in Surrogates.jl](https://surrogates.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/) shows how to make and interpolate a radial basis function.

```
using Surrogates
using LinearAlgebra
f = x -> x[1]*x[2]
lb = [1.0,2.0]
ub = [10.0,8.5]
x = sample(50,lb,ub,SobolSample())
y = f.(x)
my_radial_basis = RadialBasis(x,y,lb,ub)

#I want an approximation at (1.0,1.4)
approx = my_radial_basis((1.0,1.4))
```