# Optimizing surrogates radial basis function in Julia

Tags: julia, interpolation, radial

I am trying to implement optimization function for the radial basis using `surrogate_optimize` in the following example.

```
x = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7.5, 8]
y = [2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8.5, 9]
z = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 4]
XY = zip(x,y) |> collect
lb, ub = vcat(minimum(x),minimum(y)), vcat(maximum(x), maximum(y))

radial = Surrogates.RadialBasis(XY, z, lb, ub)

# I have tried using the surrogate_optimize directly, but i know it requires objective function,

surrogate_optimize(z, SRBF(), lb, ub, radial, UniformSample(), maxiters=50)
```

As the above implementation is wrong, hence I would like to know how to implement surrogate optimize function on the above mentioned script?

***Documentation reference:***

http://surrogates.sciml.ai/stable/radials/

http://surrogates.sciml.ai/stable/optimizations/

Thanks!

Comment: Optimization requires a function to optimize, and you have none there... it looks like you just want to do something like interpolation?

Comment: @phipsgabler thanks for the response!! The main idea is to do interpolation using `rbf` with `multiquadric radial`, here i am using `Surrogates.RadialBasis` with `linear radial`. The accuracy of my radial is very low using the above method, hence i was looking for way to improve it. But if there is a better direct approach to perform the above interpolations, please do let me know.

Comment: @phipsgabler I started with this example suggested by Chris: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325794/interpolation-with-radial-basis-function-in-julia